# Rfacebook searchPages returns 0 results

Tags: r, facebook, rfacebook

I'm trying to do some textmining with Rfacebook, but whenever I enter code for finding pages which include a string:

```
searchPages("facebook", token = fb_oauth, n = 10000)
```

I get back this error:

```
0 pages Error in searchPages("facebook", token = fb_oauth, n = 10000) : 
  No public page mentioning the string were found
```

I already know that the command searchFacebook has become deprecated since the second version of  Rfacebook, and I have seen one thread mention that searchPages has also become deprecated. Am I doing something wrong or is this command simply no longer available?

I've also tried using code from this thread ([Facebook search by keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30436425/facebook-search-by-keyword)) but I run into the same problem since it uses searchPages.

If searchPages is deprecated, any suggestions on how to still get data about key words through facebook?